# Passing a list to SQL query in Python

Tags: python, list, arguments

So I am trying to pass months as a tuple to a sql query in python as below:

```
no_of_months = 6
months = tuple(months_list[no_of_months:])
months
Out[14]: ('201708', '201709', '201710', '201711', '201712', '201801')

wrk_hours = str("""select * from dbo.month_step where month_id IN  \
                       %s and tier = 'Sil';""") %months
```

However this throws an error as below:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?

In case the months_list is needed:

```
['201702',
 '201703',
 '201704',
 '201705',
 '201706',
 '201707',
 '201708',
 '201709',
 '201710',
 '201711',
 '201712',
 '201801']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wkr_hours = str("""select * from dbo.month_step where mont_id in \
(%s) and tier = 'Sil';""")%(",".join(map(lambda x:"'"+x+"'",months_list[no_of_months:])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wrk_hours = str("""select * from dbo.month_step where month_id IN %s and tier = 'Optimum Silver';""") %[x for x in months]
wrk_hours
Out[1]: "select * from dbo.month_step where month_id IN 
        ['201708', '201709', '201710', '201711', '201712', '201801'] and tier = 'Optimum Silver';"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should the trick:-

```
list_args = ['201708', '201709', '201710', 
'201711', '201712', '201801']    
str("""select * from dbo.month_step where month_id IN (%s) and tier = 
'Sil';""") % (','.join(list_args))
```

It is simpler and works.